# How to improve deep learning with Tuning

Tags: python, deep-learning

so I used deeplearning to improve my model accuracy, but when I check with bayesian classifier I got 91.67% accuracy
then I check with deep learning, but it doesn't improve max I get 91.67%

I have to improve my accuracy, I want to try using Tuning, but I don't know how

My dataset has 3 class

So please help me, at least I get 92% accuracy

```
    import pandas
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
    from keras.utils import np_utils
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
    # load dataset
    dataframe = pandas.read_csv("pca_aug.csv", header=None)
    dataset = dataframe.values
    X = dataset[:,0:300].astype(float)
    Y = dataset[:,300]
    xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest= train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.4,random_state=0)
    
    # encode class values as integers
    def konversi(Y):
      encoder = LabelEncoder()
      encoder.fit(Y)
      encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
      # convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
      dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
      return dummy_y
    
    ytrain_dummy= konversi(ytrain)
    ytest_dummy= konversi(ytest)
    
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=300, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    nepochs = 20
    nbatch = 5
    
    
    model.fit(xtrain, ytrain_dummy, epochs=nepochs, batch_size=nbatch)
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(xtest, ytest_dummy)
    print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but how are we supposed to do it when we can't reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a limit on the accuracy, before training the model, it will introduce biases to the results. The performance metric depends on the data, noise present in the data, training, and the model.

You can use a hyperparameter searching library like `keras-tuner`.

```
import kerastuner as kt
from tensorflow import keras

def build_model(hp):
  ...
  return model

tuner = kt.RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='val_loss',
    max_trials=5)

tuner.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
best_model = tuner.get_best_models()[0]
```